# change youtube link list to embed youtube link with jquery

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have a youtube link list like this :

```
<div class="youtubecontainer">
<li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTnZJkrc5ec">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTnZJkrc5ec">Link 2</a></li>
</div>
```

And I would like to change with highslide iframe link :

```
<div class="youtubecontainer">
<li>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTnZJkrc5ec" onclick="return openYouTube(this)" class="highslide">Link 1</a>
</li>
</div>
```

I don't want to manually change and if my client add a list of youtube link, it will automatically change the list like this . Is that can do with Jquery?